# how to plot LSTM results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plot, lstm

I have a neural network with this code:

```
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10,input_shape= 
 (x_train.shape[1],1),return_sequences=True),
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10,return_sequences=True),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])
y_pred=model.predict(x_test)
```

training shape is (1000,24,1)
test shape is (250,24,1)
y_pred shape is (250,24,1)
when I try to plot y_pred this error pops up
"x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (250,) and (250, 24, 1)
"
I was wondering if you could help me how I can plot y_pred?

Comment: Read the error. your ```y_pred``` is 3D and the plot function is asking for dimensions no greater than 2D. Also, what are you plotting ```y_pred``` against? what are the ```x``` and ```y``` that you are passing into the plot function.

Comment: It is not 2D it is 3D. Also your question is vague in that it does not describe which parts of y_pred need to be plotted and against what.

Comment: I ask my question in another way. do you know why y_pred is (250,24,1)? sholudn't be (250,1)?

Comment: The way your model is configured, it returns a prediction of the shape (250,24,1). What is your model predicting. What does your input data represent and what does the output data represent.

Comment: It is time series prediton with LSTM, which predict wind speed. Dataset is devided into training and test set; then using training set x_train and y_train is constructed. And by test set x_test and y_test..... After training I used model to predict x_test, which has dimension (250,24,1). I expected y_pred to be (250,1) but it is (250,24,1). I don't know why it is like this? and also don't know how to use y_pred to calculate error ? thankyou in advance

Comment: take a look at here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#recurrent_neural_network